# Counter in a Python Subclass Callback

Tags: python

I am using the TwythonStream Calss and am trying to get a count of the numer of instance that a partcular sting is found. The code below runs but the counter stays at 1 for each instance. As a Python NOOB any help or pointers is appreciated

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer

class myStream(TwythonStreamer):

    def on_success(self, data):

        if 'text' in data:
            counter = counter + 1
            print("found %d" % counter)
        if counter == 3:
            print("Found three!")
            self.disconnect()
```

Comment: Apologies if this is some obvious part of twython...

Where are you defining the 'counter' variable?

Comment: as noted above 2 things, declare `counter = 0` at class level and in your method use `self.counter` instead, that is supossing `on_success` will be called several times by instance.

Comment: Jjpx - Thank you that change corrected the issue. I appreciate your help!